# jQuery plugin is loaded correctly, but does nothing

Tags: jquery, front-end, youtube

I'm trying to use [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer) to load a fullscreen background on a website. I've first implemented it in a static HTML on my desktop, this works fine.
I then put everything in my theme and load it up, no errors, no action.

The first thing you look at is syntax errors, typo's in URL etcs

- When I load the same code in local HTML, it works
- When I view the source of the WordPress, all the scripts get loaded correctly
- Used console.log to check if the script was loaded before initialization, it was

I'm using this code to fire it up, before the `</head>`

```
<script>
(function($) {
    var myPlayer = jQuery("#bgndVideo").YTPlayer({
        mask:{
            0:'assets/overlay.png'
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

But still no luck. For reference, the stripped down full code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/assets/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    (function($) {
        var myPlayer = jQuery("#bgvid").YTPlayer({
            mask:{
                0:'assets/overlay.png'
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>

    <?php wp_head();?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class();?>>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="bgvid" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'9CrTwCFdJnA',containment:'body', showControls:false, autoPlay:true, loop:true, vol:50, mute:true, opacity:1, quality:'large', optimizeDisplay:true}"></div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

When I try this on a local HTML I see the effect of the plugin that it loads a YouTube iframe inside the .. What's the deal? Been on and off it for a couple of days now, can't figure it out anymore.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: None, but if I make a deliberate typo I do, so the code is read..

Comment: And logging the `myPlayer`?

Comment: Seems to echo the correct instance `r.fn.init {} __proto__:Object[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the culprit, no solution yet though.
As I said the code ran well on a static HTML page, so I copied the exact static HTML into my theme, leaving all the rest out, and it didn't work.

So it had to be WordPress related, so I turned off installed plugins one by one and the issue was resolved when I disabled the [Crayon](http://wordpress.org/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/) plugin.
So now onwards in this direction, will update this answer if I find the cause (tips on how to debug something like this are welcome!).